# Code to delete nodes from a linked list that have a certain value fails to delete all of them

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I am working on this task:

> Take elements (numbers in the range of 1-50) as input from the user and create a Linked List with those elements. Then delete all nodes which have values greater than 25.

The `LinkedList` class is given, including `add(int value)`, `get(int index)` and `remove(int index)` methods. I have to implement the logic to create a linked list instance with nodes for the input values, and then to *conditionally* delete nodes from that linked list.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class q1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      list.add(i, sc.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if ((int) list.get(i) > 25) {
        list.remove(i);
      }
    }

    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Whenever I run this code, i still get a value greater than 25 in the result list.

This is what I entered:

```
[23, 45, 12, 34, 34, 66, 25, 13, 12, 24, 33]
```

And this is the output I get:

```
[23, 12, 34, 25, 13, 12, 24]
```

Note how there still is a value 34 in the result that shouldn't be there.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Go through your code step by step, either with a tool like a debugger or with paper and pencil

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you remove a node at index `i`, the next node (that had index `i+1`) will be at that index `i`, but still your loop increases `i`, which means that this "next" node will never be inspected.

In practice this means that if you have two *consecutive* nodes that have a value greater than 25, only the first of these two will be removed.

There are many ways to solve this, but a quick fix is to have `i` start at the end and have it move towards the beginning (to 0):

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if ((int) list.get(i) > 25) {
    list.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Now it will produce the expected results.

Still, this algorithm is not very efficient, since `.get(i)` will have to iterate the list each time from the start, giving this algorithm a time complexity of O(²). This is not optimal.

Better is to write a function that will iterate **once** through the list and will remove nodes (with a certain condition) *during* that single traversal. Then you'll have a time complexity of O().

Comment: Did you mean `giving this algorithm a time complexity of O(*)`?

Comment: That's what I meant. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are modifying `LinkedList` while looping over its original size which get changed after element removal which intern causes the index inside loop pointing to incorrect values

if we look it with visualisation it will be more clear

```
INDEX    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
       [23, 45, 12, 34, 34, 66, 25, 13, 12, 24, 33]
         i

SIZE    11
```

when loop started the `size` and `i` position in `LinkedList` is shown.

when element greater than 25 is found on position 1 let see what happens

```
INDEX    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
       [23, 12, 34, 34, 66, 25, 13, 12, 24, 33]
             i

SIZE    10
```

As we can see from the visualisation `size` is now 10 and `i` is 1

From this we can see few problems

- On the next iteration of loop it will skip element at current `i` position which should be checked

The same process happens again and again every time element greater than 25 is found the next element is not going to be validated and will intern remain in the `LinkedList` even if it is greater than 25

To solve the problem as state by @tricot you can either loop over the `LinkedList` starting from the end

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if ((int) list.get(i) > 25) {
    list.remove(i);
  }
}
```

which leads to time complexity of `O(²)`.

A better approach would be to create `ListIterator` and using it to remove element greater than 25 in `LinkedList` which will give time complexity of `O()`

```
ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next() > 25) {
    it.remove()
  }
}
```

Reference to `ListIterator` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove--)